Crashes in Swift App Using Swift Data Concurrently
I’m experiencing intermittent crashes in my iOS app (Swift 6), which heavily relies on concurrency. A small percentage of users experience vague crashes with no apparent reason.
Here’s an overview of my setup:

The app uses Swift Data for data storage.
Background tasks are handled with Task.detached, while UI updates are managed using MainActor.run or
DispatchQueue.main.async/sync.
A single ModelContainer is initialized and stored as a global variable.
ModelContext instances are created dynamically for each task and are not shared. Each context and its associated models are isolated
per task.
Various thread synchronization techniques are employed to ensure logical consistency.

Despite following the above guidelines, I'm seeing vague crashes of EXC_BAD_ACCESS, KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS, EXC_BREAKPOINT. Mostly seem related to internal Swift Data mechanisms.
Questions:

Is there anything inherently flawed in this approach?
Specifically, is it problematic to use a ModelContext in an async function (ensuring a single execution path per ModelContext) without enclosing it in a ModelActor?

Any insights or recommendations are much appreciated!

Anytime you leave the MainActor you should not be using the container.mainContext. Also, don’t mix GCD with async/await, forget about GCD unless you have an exception reason/understanding.

Are you using ModelActor for background tasks? It's the recommended approach for using SwiftData (insert/update/delete) outside of the main actor.

@JoakimDanielson – IMHO, ModelActor introduces weird problems. I use actors, but scrupulously avoid ModelActor, e.g., nestsarau’s approach.

UriP – We cannot possibly comment on your ModelContext approach without a representative example. Even better, construct a MRE that manifests the problem. (Yes, I imagine/understand that you’re getting “random” crashes and probably cannot yet reproduce it consistently yourself, but that really is the first step: Create a new blank project that repeatedly does the sorts of things that your production app does, and keep iterating on that MRE until you successfully reproduce the problem.)

I must confess that the references to detached tasks, MainActor.run {…}, GCD, etc., are all red-flags. If your properties/methods are properly isolated, the use of those patterns are often become largely redundant. But, again, it is impossible to say without some representative code snippets.

@Rob thanks for the links, I need to investigate this further.

@Rob Thank you for your answer. My purpose was to discuss the principles, which you've managed to pinpoint as red flags. Could you please LMK what would you suggest instead in order to start background work, and go back from background to main? I feel like I'm missing a lengthy article about this from Apple, but can't find any.

For background Swift Data, I use an actor, like nestsarau’s. That gets it off the main actor. For properties that will be published for the UI, I would mark those as being isolated to the main actor with @MainActor qualifiers. That ensures that they will be published to the main actor. The idea with both is that rather than relying on GCD-like patterns like MainActor.run {…} and Task.detached {…} (placing the burden on your shoulders), let the compiler take care of it.

WWDC 2021’s Swift concurrency: Update a sample app is a great practical demonstration of migrating to Swift concurrency (e.g., replacing DispatchQueue.global().async {…} and DispatchQueue.main.async {…} with actor isolation). It even shows how you could shift from GCD to MainActor.run {…}, but then goes on to show how proper actor-isolation renders even that unnecessary. The newer Migrate your app to Swift 6 builds on that, to discuss migration issues unique to Swift 6.
